# How Do I Capture The Value From This HTML?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am very new to javascript and coding in general, and I am trying to capture the Order Number value from a hidden div on my confirmation page.

Could someone help me out? I imagine this will be very simple. Here is my code:

I am adding this to Google Tag Manager so I can send the order ID back to the ad platforms.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <div id="zGTMOrderData">
            <input name="M$M$zGTMOrderData_OrderNumber" type="hidden" id="M_M_zGTMOrderData_OrderNumber" value="27664425">
        </div>
    

     <script>
     var getOrderNumber = function() {
     document.getElementById("M_M_zGTMOrderData_OrderNumber").value;
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using GTM, you should not do custom JavaScript (that defies the purpose of having GTM). Instead, go to "variables", click "new", click "variable type", and select "DOM Element" from the list. Make sure "Selection Method" is set to "ID" and enter the id of your element.

[image: GTM DOM variable configuration]

The value will only be available for tags that fire after the element is rendered, so triggers with "DOM Ready" are a good bet (but then you have the same caveat for you custom script).

The DOM variable type will return by default the innerText (or value, in the case of form fields) of the element. You can also enter an attribute name, in which case the variable will return the value of the attribute.

Also, if you insist on custom Javascript you still need to set up a variable with GTM to catch the value, so using the built-in saves you a step.

Comment: In my case, I am firing a trigger on page view. Would I need to adjust the conversion trigger to fire on DOM Page View to make sure the trigger matches the Variable configuration?

Comment: Yes. The page view trigger fires as soon as the container script is loaded, which is usually before any DOM elements are rendered. The value is only available when the form element is actually rendered by the browser.

Comment: When I did as you suggested, I am not getting any value pulled in. I have my trigger set to DOM Ready | Page URL Contains | thank-you. 

I set my variable as a DOM Element. When I ran my test, no value was returned. I can't figure out why the value isn't being pulled in.

Comment: It might have to do with the fact that this is a hidden field. This article: https://www.kerstner.at/2015/03/retrieving-value-of-hidden-input-dom-element-in-google-tag-manager-gtm/ suggests that you should set the 'attribute' field to 'value' to retrieve the form value.

Comment: Yes! I set the Attribute Namee to 'value' and that was the trick! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("M_M_zGTMOrderData_OrderNumber").value;`

Add the `return` keyword at line start to make this the return value of the function.

there are 3 general approaches you can take actually:

returning the value

```
var getOrderNumber = function() {
     return document.getElementById("M_M_zGTMOrderData_OrderNumber").value;
```

direct assignment (if you just need to assign the value to variable, there isn't really need of a function right now)

```
var getOrderNumber = document.getElementById("M_M_zGTMOrderData_OrderNumber").value;
```

Assigning to a variable in the outer scope of the function

```
var orderNumber = null;
getOrderNumber = function() {
orderNumber = document.getElementById("M_M_zGTMOrderData_OrderNumber").value;
}
getOrderNumber()
// now orderNumber stores the computed value
```

Comment: when I try testing out what you said here (https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_state_return2), I am not seeing any value being returned.

Comment: I do see an "Hello John", which is a return value from the function. Try removing the return keyword and it will return undefined, even if in the function it computes the sentence.

Comment: Oh - that must have sent you the W3 School default code. When I replace it with the code above plus the solution you've given me, I am still not seeing any value returned.

Comment: I think you are talking of more steps than your OP conveys. My solution shows how to store the value correctly in a variable. https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-sunset-t2n68?file=/index.html in the sandbox console you can see the value logged correctly. From there to display it requires more code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var getOrderNumber = function() { // your function is not closed
  const inputValue = document.getElementById("M_M_zGTMOrderData_OrderNumber").value;
  // have fun with inputValue
} // close the function
```